# Circuitry for the DRV8840 Motor Driver

Tags: pcb, motor, h-bridge, debugging, prototyping

I'm building a circuit based on the DRV8840 (datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8840.pdf). Unfortunately, I can't get it to work. I think something might be wrong with my design. When I apply the "ENABLE" pulse at 5V, there is no actuation of the motor. I've checked the motor with a DC signal and its fine. I've also checked the voltage levels around the board and the soldering of the board and it all seems solid. Any ideas???

[image]

Comment: What have you done with the other 2 inputs when you apply 5V to ENABLE?

Comment: Also a note - pin 18 NFAULT appears to be an output, but you've tied it to your +5V net.

Comment: Are you actually feeding it from 9V or maybe less?

Comment: Yea. I'm feeding from 9V. The IC says that it operates above 8.2V.

Comment: The other two inputs (Phase and Decay) are set to low. Phase low means it operates in one direction versus the other. And Decay means it operates in Coast mode rather than Brake. To my knowledge, those shouldn't effect the operation of the motor.

Comment: I've got NFAULT tied to 5V rail with a pull-up and I've actually got an LED on it. No faults have been detected. Literally at a loss on what to try to debug next. I've resoldered the entire thing (with a new IC) and I've rewired it twice.

Answer (score 2):

As there is no sense resistor connected between the ISEN pins and ground there will be no current chopping at a set value.  Depending on the characteristics of the DC motor you are driving, enabling the device could ramp current above the internal current limit and thereby cause the open-collector fault line to be enabled.

As you have tied the fault line to 5V this could pull down this rail and possibly disable the device by cycling nSLEEP, nRESET, etc.

Comment: I agree. After fighting this part myself (you must set the I pins to something even if disabling current chopping BTW), I suggest connecting fault with a proper pull-up.